# PHP Put Request Philips Hue

Tags: php, philips-hue

I have the following code to set the color of a Philips lightbulb.

```
<?php

$arrData['hue'] = 46920;
$arrData['sat'] = 254;
$arrData['bri'] = 254;

$data = json_encode($arrData);
echo $data;

$url = "http://MYSITE/api/1234567890/lights/1/state";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8078);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response; 

?>
```

I essentially want to make a PUT request `{"hue":46920,"sat":254,"bri":255}` to http://MYSITE:8078/api/USER/lights/1/state except it just times out. Here is the output of the clip API debugger

[image]

What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: You want to make POST request, but you are using PUT for `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`?

Comment: Sorry I meant Put request

Comment: You say it times out. Can you ping the address?

Comment: Hmm well I think the issue is that my site can't ping the site and port. It is able to work fine through command window though

Comment: I was able to have it be successful if I used `CURLOPT_PROXY` but why would it not work from my website?

Comment: Problem solved. My Hosting provider was blocking requests to non-standard ports (8078).